# See which libraries have been loaded, and why?

Tags: 10

I'm working on removing the jQuery dependency from my website, and it's proving to be a hassle.

Cleaning my own custom modules and themes was easy enough, but now I'm left perusing the contrib modules I'm using, trying to figure out which module is somehow still leaning on jQuery. Devel can show me which libraries were loaded on a page, but that means I have to hop from *.libraries.yml to *.libraries.yml trying to figure out where a jQuery dependency comes from.

Is there an easier way to do this? Something similar to `composer show --tree` or `composer depends core:jquery`, but for Drupal libraries loaded on a page?